# Typechecking in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactive-programming

I have a multilevel hierarchy class A-> class B-> class C through which I have to pass numbers.

The parent class is the App class like this-

```
import propTypes from 'prop-types';
        class App extends React.Component{
             constructor(props){
                 super(props);
                 this.state={
                    text:0,
                    isClicked:false
             }
           this.display=this.display.bind(this);
        }
        display(){
        var num=document.getElementById('number').value; 
        var text=parseInt(num);
        this.setState({
          isClicked:true,
          text:text
        })

      }
        render(){
        return(
        <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-6">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter name" value={this.state.label}/> 
                  <input type="text" type='number' id='number'/>
                  <button onClick={this.display}>Click here</button>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6">
                  <Display click={this.state.isClicked} data={this.state.text}/>
                </div>
              </div>

            )
          }
        }
        App.propTypes={
          text:propTypes.number,
          num:propTypes.number,
          data:propTypes.number
        }
```

The Display class is the child class of App class and it is like this

import propTypes from 'prop-types';
class Display extends React.Component{

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        num:this.props.data,//This value of number is coming as undefined
        value:0
    }

  }
  render(){
    //console.log(this.state.data);
    if(this.props.isClicked===true){
        return(<DonutChart data={this.state.num}/>)
    }else{
        return(<DonutChart data={this.state.value}/>)
      }     
  }
}

Display.propTypes={
  data:propTypes.number,
  num:propTypes.number
}
```

And the child class of Display class is DonutChart class which is like this

```
import propTypes from 'prop-types';
 const DonutChart= React.createClass({
      propTypes:{
        data:React.PropTypes.number,
          },
      getDefaultProps(){
        return{
          value:0,
          size:116
        }
      },
      render(){
        //console.log(this.props.data); This comes as 0 on the console
        return(
          <svg height={this.props.size} width={this.props.size}>

          </svg>

        )
      }
    })
```

I get this error as 'expected number but got a string' error in React. And the value of data is not getting passed to the child classes. What is the problem here?

Answer (score -2):

You want `this.props.data.size` and your propTypes declaration in Donutchart is also erroneous also in your parent component you are only passing `data` instead of `this.state.data`. For your Donut chart, you could use a `stateless functional component` because you container component can handle state and props, Your chart's only job is to display info.

Comment: why this.props.data.size in propTypes of DoutChart?

Comment: console.log this.props and see what it contains.

Comment: cannot read property number of undefined for data in Display class

Comment: It should be `PropTypes` and not `propTypes` when defining types in `Display.propTypes`

Comment: You have some syntax and logic errors. I suggest you mark this question answered.

Comment: I have imported propTypes from react. So why I should I use PropTypes?